# How to handle progress events with GeckoFX

Tags: .net, browser

I want to be able to display the page loading status (i.e. waiting for server, downloading page, etc) using GeckoFX.

The Navigating event is perfect for letting me know when a page has started loading, but I need to know when it is finished loading.

I know the GeckoWebBrowser class has an IsBusy property. I could run a timer and to check this and update the status but this is just a hack at best.

I'm not trying to create a full blown browser here, just some basics. Can anyone nudge me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[It has a DocumentCompleted event too](http://code.google.com/p/geckofx/source/browse/trunk/Skybound.Gecko/GeckoWebBrowser.cs).

Comment: So it does. Excuse my temporary blindness and accept my thanks